# How to find something concrete in a mongodb document?

Tags: mongodb

I have a databse on mongodb with many documents that looks like this:

```
"_id" : ObjectId("5e7a26d516b792496f9b8824"),
"line":'127.0.0.1 cristina [10/Oct/2000:13:55:25-0700] "GET/apache_pb.gif,HTTP/1.0" 200 2326 "[http://www.example.com/start.html](http://www.example.com/start.html)" "Mozilla/4.08[en](Win98;I;Nav)"'
```

I need to find every log that has the route 'apache_pb.gif' like the one in this example. Thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with `.find` operator

try this:

```
db.your_collection_name.find({line : /apache_pb.gif/})
```

- you can use all REGEX forms.

ALSO
`$match` operator should work and give you the docs as an output

try this:

```
db.your_collection_name.aggregate( [ { $match: { line: /apache_pb.gif/ } } ] )
```

Try MongoDB great documentation -> https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/regexFind/index.html